# Prove Borel Sets

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets

Proof $[a,b], (a,b], [a,b)$ are borel sets.

I read from book, the definition of Borel sets :

> Borel sets is smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all open sets.

But I cannot understand it.

Please help me.

Comment: I've recently been thinking about Borel sets myself, so I can sympathize.  A $\sigma$-algebra just means a collection that's closed under complements, countable unions, and countable intersections.  So can you use these operations to construct closed and half-open intervals from the open sets?  Hint:  Use the fact that $\Bbb Q$ (which is countable) is dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The definition you quote is of a Borel _algebra_ on a topological space $(X,\tau)$. Basically, a Borel algebra on $X$ is the collection of all Borel sets on $X$. A Borel set is defined as a set which can be constructed from open sets with the operations of countable unions, countable intersections and complementation.

Answer (score 2):

1. $ \{a\}$ and $ \{b\}$ are closed, hence Borel.
2. $[a,b]= (a,b) \cup  \{a\} \cup \{b\}$.
3. $[a,b)= (a,b) \cup  \{a\} .$
4. $(a,b]$ is your turn !

Comment: $(a,b]=(a,b) \cup \{b\}$
Then how to proof?

Comment: @liswyhy: $(a,b)$ and $\{b\}$ are both Borel sets, so their union must be ...

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

$[a,b]=\cap_n (a-\frac 1 n, b+\frac 1 n)$, $(a,b]=\cap_n (a, b+\frac 1 n)$ and $[a,b)=\cap_n (a-\frac 1 n, b)$.

Comment: So, how to proof

Comment: @liswyhy Open intervals are open sets, so they are Borel sets. Any countable union/intersection of Borel sets is Borel.

Comment: thank you so much